The core of an $\infty$-category and pointwise invertible maps $\Delta^1 \times \partial \Delta^n \cup \{1\} \times \Delta^n \to \underline \hom(B,X)$
I'm currently working through Theorem 3.5.11 of Cisinski's Higher Categories and Homotopical Algebra. The section in which the theorem is inscribed concers the core of an $\infty$-category.
Trying to understand this I have come up with two related questions.
Recall that, denoting $k(C)$ the maximal groupoid of a $1$-category $C$, and $\tau$ the homotopy category construction, the core of an $\infty$-category $C$ is defined as the pullback of the morphisms $C \to N\tau(C)$ and $N(k(\tau(C))) \to N(\tau(C))$.
Question 1. It seems to me that a simplicial map $F : X \to Y$ corestricts to $k(Y)$ if and only if $\tau X \to \tau Y$ corestricts to $k(\tau Y)$. That is, if $F$ maps all $1$-simplices to invertible simplices of $Y$. Is this correct?
More generally, given $A$ and $B$ two $\infty$-categories, one defines an $\infty$-category $k(A,B)$ as the pullback of the restriction map $\underline \hom(A,B) \to \underline \hom(ob(A), B)$ and the inclusion $k(\underline \hom(ob(A),B)) \to \underline \hom(ob(A),B)$. (Here $\underline \hom(A,B)_n = \hom(A \times \Delta^n, B)$ and $ob(A)$ is the constant simplcial set with $0$-simplices as those of $A$.) In particular $k(\Delta^0, B) = k(B)$.
Following up Question 1, a map $F \colon X \to \underline \hom(A,B)$ would corestrict to $k(A,B)$ if, upon restricting to $ob(A)$, it factors through $k(\underline \hom(ob(A),B))$. If the answer to Question 1 is affirmative, then this would mean that $F| \colon X \to \underline \hom(ob(A),B)$ maps all $1$-simplices of $X$ to invertible $1$-simplices. Again, this is a condition which seems to depend only of $X_1$.
In the proof of the aforementioned theorem, the author deduces that a map $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^n \to \underline \hom(B,X)$ factors through $k(B,X)$ from the fact that it restriction to $\Delta^1 \times \partial \Delta^n \cup \{1\} \times \Delta^n$ does.
Roughly speaking, the argument is that all maps $(0,k) \to (1,k)$ and $(1,k) \to (1,k-1)$ are sent to isomorphisms, hence the maps $(0,k) \to (0,k+1)$ satisfy the same property (and every $1$-simplex is a composition of these).
However:
Question 1. For $n > 1$, isn't the above immediate from the fact that $\Delta^1 \times \Delta^n$ has the same $1$-skeleton as $\Delta^1 \times \partial \Delta^n \cup \{1\} \times \Delta^n$?

The answer to Question 1 is yes. Indeed, by the universal property of the pullback, a map $F\colon X\to Y$ factors through $k(Y)\to Y$ iff the composite $X\to Y\to\tau Y$ factors through $k(\tau Y)\to \tau(Y)$. This is already saying that all $1$-simplices of $X$ must be sent to isomorphisms in $\tau(Y)$, i.e. to equivalences in $Y$. By the universal property of $\tau X$ (noting that $\tau Y$ and $k(\tau Y)$ are both $1$-categories), there is a unique factorization of $X\to Y \to\tau Y$ as a composite $X\to \tau X\to \tau Y$, where the last map in this composite is $\tau F$. As such, asking for this composite to factor through $k(\tau Y)\to \tau Y$ is equivalent to asking for $\tau F\colon \tau X\to \tau Y$ to factor through $k(\tau Y)\to\tau Y$. All in all, this shows that $F\colon X\to Y$ corestricts to $k(Y)$ iff $\tau F\colon\tau X\to \tau Y$ corestricts to $k(\tau Y)$.
The answer to Question 2 is also yes. As you noted, $\Delta^1\times\Delta^n\to\underline{\mathrm{hom}}(B,X)$ factors through $k(B,X)\to\underline{\mathrm{hom}}(B,X)$ iff the composite $\Delta^1\times\Delta^n\to\underline{\mathrm{hom}}(B,X)\to\underline{\mathrm{hom}}(\mathrm{ob}(B),X)$ factors through $k(\underline{\mathrm{hom}}(\mathrm{ob}(B),X))\to\underline{\mathrm{hom}}(\mathrm{ob}(B),X)$, and this is a condition only on the $1$-simplices of $\Delta^1\times\Delta^n$, and these are indeed already all contained in $\Delta^1\times\partial\Delta^n\cup\{1\}\times\Delta^n$ if $n\geq 2$. I guess the reason Cisinski does not mention this is that it does not matter for his argument if $n=1$ or $n\geq 2$, and you have to cover $n=1$ via his argument anyway. You can choose to omit a case distinction if one of the cases would in a sense imply the other anyway.

Awesome, thank you very much for the comprehensive answer.
